# How to test that a method throws an exception on specific input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, nsubstitute

In the method below, when `model.test` is empty I want this method to throw an exception.

```
public bool Create(Test model)
{
    if (model.test == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("nanana.");

    }
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { throw; }
}
```

Here is my current test:

```
[Test]
public void Only_one_property_should_be_set()
{
    var rep  =  Substitute.For<ITestRepository>();

    var x = rep.Create(model.ToEntity());

    Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => rep.Create(model.ToEntity()));
}
```

It's not working, because x returns always as false.

I could substitute `TestRepository` directly, but then I would insert items into the DB, which I don't want to do.  How do I test the repository exceptions with NUnit and NSubstitute without inserting items into the database?

Comment: Well you're not testing the code you've provided at all - you're testing a mock. You should mock out the dependency (if you really need to), not the class you're trying to test.

Comment: Im not totallyt understand what i exaclty have to do, can u describe a little more?

Comment: Well it's not clear what you're trying to achieve to start with... but if you're substituting out the class that contains the method you're trying to test, that's a bad start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several problems with what you're doing.  As has already been said in the comments, it's generally a bad idea to Mock / Substitute the class that you're trying to test.  Mocks and Substitutes are used to allow you to control the flow of logic through your code under test, not to replace your code under test.

Since the code you've shown doesn't have any dependencies, other than the model class, there's no reason for your to use a Substitute at all in this situation.  You would use a Substitute if your code looked like this (pseudo code)

```
if(model.Test == null) {
   throw someException
}
_someDependency->Create(model.Value1, model.Value2, model.Test)
```

In the code above, `_someDependency` is some underlying database interaction class that has been injected into the repository, via it's constructor.  You would then be able to create a Substitute for `_someDependency` in order to influence the flow of the `Create` method, or verify the interaction with the dependency.

As far as testing the method as is currently stands, there's no reason why you can't just pass in a Model that has `test==null`.  The flow of logic in the method is such that if that test fails, you wouldn't expect data to be written to the database, that's the point of the check.  So, your test could simply look like this:

```
[Test]
public void CreateShouldThrowIfModelTestIsNull()
{
    var testModel = model.ToEntity();

    var sut  =  new TestRepository();

    testModel.test = null;

    try {
        sutCreate(testModel);
        Assert.Fail("Expected Exception");
    } catch(InvalidOperationException ex) {
        Assert.AreEqual("nanana.", ex.Message);
    }
}
```